# Postestimation test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, f-test

I have run two regression models. one is GLM with logit link and Binomial family and the other is tobit regression. I want to compare the coefficient of some of my independent variables in each model. I have tried the Wald test '' Test command'' in stata.

But, I am not sure if that is correct to use it for a GLM regression model too. Would you please recommend me an appropriate test of hypothesis to be used after GLM and Tobit.

Comment: Is this question stupid to ask or why no one is pointing any idea.

Comment: Request you to wait for some more time. It's been just two hours since you have posted this question. Patience will yield a good response to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The Wald test doesn't allow you to "compare the coefficients" of the independent variables *across* models, as you seem to intend. It is meant to test a restriction on one or more coefficients (say $\beta = 0$) in one specific model.